# Dropdown control searching method

Tags: c#, vb.net

In the below **form** a **grid** contains a **dropDown** control which contains products that should enter on the **grid**, **dropDown** fills on the **form load event**, A-Z products are present in the **dropDown**.

See the image below:

[click here to see my form and dropdown http://imageshack.com/a/img838/5697/1knn.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img838/5697/1knn.jpg)

As you can see, when I press "G" it will show product names that start with G and others also. What I want is: *If I press 'G' it should show product names that start with G only.*

```
Dim adapter As New NpgsqlDataAdapter(strSql, GenConnection)
adapter.Fill(SourceDataSetProducts)
bindSourceSale.DataSource = SourceDataSetProducts
SourceDataSetProducts.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {SourceDataSetProducts.Columns("ProductId")}
drpDwnProducts.DataSource = Nothing
drpDwnProducts.DataSource = bindSourceSale
drpDwnProducts.DisplayMember = "ProductName"
drpDwnProducts.ColumnHeaders = True
drpDwnProducts.Width = 800
```

In this way, I used to fill the dropDown in form load.

Comment: http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/combobox-with-autocomplete-textbox-in-vb.net

Comment: @NagarajS S  using C1(Component One Controls) autocompletion properties are not available for them

Comment: dear for your dropdown just make autocompet property to true and dropdown style = dropdown

Comment: @Developerzzz there is no option to enable autocomplete ([ http://imageshack.com/a/img837/5805/pwv4.jpg ]) because am using component one (C1) control

Comment: Handle the keypress for the combobox. You can take your input and do a query to fill the combobox based on that input.

Comment: @Mr CoDeXeR there is no combobox associate with that dropdown , dropdown is set for the grid ([ http://imageshack.com/a/img838/5697/1knn.jpg ])

Comment: Or do a filter on your data source.

Comment: @Mr CoDeXeR How to ??

Comment: Does it have a keypress event?

Comment: @Mr CoDeXeR  YES for both grid and dropdown

Comment: Create a dataview from the table you need, then you data source for your binding set it to this new view, then set your dropdown.data source to your binding source. Then apply a filter to this binding source;  ex: source.Filter. = "productsname like' g'" example only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ' Get a DataView of the table contained in the dataset. 
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection = set1.Tables
    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))

' Create a BindingSource and set its DataSource property to 
' the DataView. 
Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
source1.DataSource = view1

' Set the data source for the products...
Dropdown.DataSource = source1

' The Filter string can include Boolean expressions.
source1.Filter = "products = 'whatever'"
```

You can use like as well...

```
 Source.Filter = "products like' %whatever%'"
```

This is a good start for what you need.